# Pytorch gradient calculation with two different models

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am new to pytorch and this is what I want to do:

I have two models that are related to one another: modelA and modelB. I want to get three separate gradients. I am able to get the first two without any issues, but I am not sure how I can get the third one.

1. differentiating the loss of modelA wrt modelA.parameters

   ```
    [v.grad.data for v in modelA.parameters()]
   ```
2. differentiating the loss of modelB wrt modelB.parameters

   ```
    [v.grad.data for v in modelB.parameters()]
   ```
3. differentiating the loss of modelB wrt modelA.parameters

This is what I tried:

```
    torch.autograd.grad(lossB, modelA.parameters())
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: This means `lossB` is not scalar. What is the output of `print(lossB.shape)`?

Comment: lossB.shape is torch.Size([7]). My batch size is 7.

Comment: Then it's not a scalar, you either take its average across this batch: use `lossB.mean()` as the loss instead